# How to make sure that only one video will be played at a time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement, augmented-reality

I created an AR App that plays a video on a particular image anchor. I wanted to extend that application to deal with more than 1 image. Now when I scan 1st image it plays the video, and when I scan the 2nd image it plays another video. The Problem that occurs here is both videos are playing simultaneously.

The Code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let node = SCNNode()
    
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
        
        //below code needs to be duplicated in order to add more news
        
        if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "harrypotter" {
            
            let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "harrypotter.mp4")
            
            videoNode.play()
            
            let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 360))
            
            videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
            
            videoNode.yScale = -1.0
            
            videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
            
            
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
            
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            
        }

        if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "deatheater" {
         
         let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "deatheater.mp4")
            
            videoNode.play()
         
         let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 360))
         
         videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
         
         videoNode.yScale = -1.0
         
         videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
         
         
         let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
         
         plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
         
         let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
         
         planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
         
         node.addChildNode(planeNode)
         
     }
```

i tried to use 2 if conditions which helps to play a video on a particular image anchor. Now when I scan 1st image it plays the video, and when I scan the 2nd image it plays another video. The Problem that occurs here is both videos are playing simultaneously. I want that whenever I play the another video the 1st video should be stop automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to get what you want and improve your code.

- Instead of duplicating code for each image, create a function that does all this.
- Keep track of the currently playing song so that you can stop it.

I'm not familiar with these APIs but you'd get something like this:

```
class Player
{
    private let rootNode = SCNNode()
    private var playingNode: SCNNode?

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor)
    {
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor
        {
            if let newNode = playVideo(names: imageAnchor.referenceImage.name)
            {
                <inset code to stop playing 'playingNode' and remove it>

                playingNode = newNode
            }
        }
    }

    private func playVideo(named name: String) -> SCNNode?
    {
        guard <check if video file with 'name' exists> else { return nil }

        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "\(name).mp4") 
        videoNode.play()
            
        let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 360))
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2,
                                     y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
        videoNode.yScale = -1.0
        videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
            
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                             height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
         
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        return planeNode
    }
}
```